# "Hostile alien actions" when no one is in their room

Tags: the-captain-is-dead

The rules for "Perform Hostile Alien Actions" says:

> If an alien finds a character in any location other than their start location:
>
> 1. Move the concealment down 10% for each player in the room
> 2. If a patrol of lieutenant is present, all players are injured
> 3. The lowest ranking alien goes with all characters to the infirmary
> 4. Patrol aliens move one space on their patrol path
> 5. If a hacker alien is present, all unlocked systems are locked

To me, this suggests that the patrol and hackers only move, or re-lock *if* a character is found.

Does anyone else read it this way? Can anyone clarify this?
So far, we've been treating it as if they happen all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do perform all actions listed if possible. So in the case where there are no players present steps 1-3 don't happen and if there are no unlocked systems present step 5 doesn't happen. This is poorly worded in that section of the rules but if you look closer at the example gameplay they give it shows step 4 happening even with no players present.

[Rules](https://www.alderac.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/CiD_LD_Rules_Lockdown_Press.pdf)

> You’ve used up your actions, so it is time to draw your
>   end of turn Alert. You draw “Patrol.” Two Alien Patrol
>   appear in the Warden’s Office Hallway. Luckily, no one
>   is there, but these are Patrol Aliens. **They don’t just sit
>   still and wait for the action to come to them. When you
>   PERFORM HOSTILE ALIEN ACTIONS, they both move
>   into the Mess Hall** and find you there. An alarm sounds
>   and the Concealment Level goes down by 10%. One
>   of them injures you and escorts you to the Infirmary/
>   Holding Cell while the other stays behind, ready to
>   continue its patrol on subsequent turns.

(added bolding)

If follow through the example it shows two patrol aliens in a room with no players and has them moving to the next room where they find a player. Once they find the player they perform steps 1-3 as normal but they do not perform step 4 again.

The critical thing to note that unless players are in sequential rooms along the patrol path having them not move when no player is present really takes away alot of the power of the patrol aliens and makes it a lot easier to avoid them.

Comment: I did see that, but seemed contradictory. Thanks for clarifying!